# Websocket Client only sends message once when `send` is being called several times

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

I'm making a library for adding multiplayer to python games. The library is an extra layer above the [websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/) library. I'm currently writing a test for it where two squares are controlled by two clients and move on both clients. Whenever the square is moved, I send an update to the server. The first time I do this, it works fine. However, any subsequent sends, and the message just seems to get lost. I get past the `websocket.send` call at the client but the message doesn't arrive at the server.

Originally I thought the message wasn't being handled correctly on the server's side. However if I keep moving the square around, the websocket times out even though I should be sending loads of messages.

The code to receive the messages:

```py
async for msg_json in websocket:
    print("Message received")
    msg = loads(msg_json)
    self.msg_handler(msg, new_client.id)
    print("Message handled")
```

The code to send the messages:

```py
async def send_update():
    msg = {"type": "update", "content": {"x": self.x, "y": self.y}, "id": self.id}
    await client.send(dumps(msg))
    print("Sent update")
```

Thanks in advance!